# Pound SSL Wrapper Wordpress Login Issue

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, session-cookies, pound

my Setup is like this

Visitor -> Pound -> Varnish -> nginx

My Wordpress site is looking fine from the front end (with https), but as soon i try to login to the backend this error comes up "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

When i take Pound out of the chain it works fine (with Varnish only http) but nginx directly without varnish also with SSL.

This is my pound config

```
User            "www-data"
Group           "www-data"
LogLevel        1
Alive           30
Control "/var/run/pound/poundctl.socket"

ListenHTTP
    Address  0.0.0.0
    Port     80
    Service
        BackEnd
            Address 127.0.0.1
            Port    6081
        End
    End
End

ListenHTTPS
    HeadRemove "X-Forwarded-Proto"
    AddHeader  "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
    Address    0.0.0.0
    Port       443
    Cert       "/etc/ssl/domain.com/mycert.pem"

    Service
        BackEnd
            Address 127.0.0.1
            Port    6081
        End
    End
End
```

Server is Ubuntu 14.04

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to add bellow given commands in wp-config.php file of wordpress

```
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

and make sure its pasted above the bellow line of code in wp-config.php file :)

```
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```